# JPA Trigger to replace inserted ID when value already exists

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, triggers

I have a webservice that is getting approx 9GB of raw text data per day from various sources. The vast majority of this is relatively short (100-300) character strings that are repeated very often. I might only have a few thousand unique strings

I usually do not want to pre-optimize, but our storage issues are going to become a problem very soon into development.

I have a JPA Entity, and will simplify for the sake of this posting. This is a string/id pair that is mapped to a parent table.

```
@Entity
public class DeduplicatedString implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}




public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private String value;
public DeduplicatedString() {
    super();
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

I'd like to setup a JPA listener (beforeInsert?) to check existing data when adding a new string, and return an existing record if the exact match is already found.

I'd normally just setup an on insert trigger, and am not so sure how to do this in JPA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you need is not directly supported by JPA. There is a `@PrePersist` annotation (along with [several others](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events)), but these can only be used to e.g. monitor the system, or make last-minute changes to the entity. JPA is unaware of any triggers executed in the database, and there are currently no mechanisms to link the two.

Comment: Can I put in a bunch of arbitrary SQL that will be run whenever JPA creates my tables for me?

Comment: It depends - which JPA provider do you use? EclipseLink, for example, allows you to do this: you can specify your own stored procedure or custom SQL query to be executed for any CRUD operation. See this link for more details: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CRUDStoredProcedures

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by pointer?  Do you mean you do not want to insert the record?

In general to do this in your application you should first query for the object with the string, and only persist a new one if it is not found.

Comment: Right. I want to do exactly this. I know I can use an insert trigger or Sproc to query and return an existing record, or add a new one if it does not yet exist. Can I do this with JPA / JPA Listeners?